# Laravel 5 webapp not working becasuse of mbstring

Tags: php, nginx, redhat, mbstring

I migrated a Laravel 5 webapp from one server to new server. This webapp is working with nginx and php-fpm. I installed php by downloading php tar file and compiling.

When I do curl http://127.0.0.1:80 I have the following error:

> **Fatal error**:  Call to undefined function Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\mb_internal_encoding() in **/var/www/php/dashboard/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php** on line **43**

I know that I get files related to mbstring on path /opt/php-5.6.30/ext/mbstring

I enabled `zend.multibyte = On` and `extension=php_mbstring.dll` on `php.ini` localted on `/usr/local/php/php.ini`. I rebooted and executed `php-fpm` but I'm without success.

Nginx version 1.12.2, PHP version 5.6.36. Redhat 7.6.
I can't install by `yum install php-mbstring`. Configure Command `./configure --enable-fpm --with-mysql` on `php.ini`.

How can I enable mbstring?

Comment: Why are you using php 5?? Use 7+ please!

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your php version to 7+. You cannot use php 5.6 unless you are using laravel 5.4 or below

Comment: Iim using laravel 5.0.35. I downloaded php 7.3.7 but how can I configure enabling every modules including fpm, mysql and mbstring?